# gdb: how to tell whether some piece of memory is marked read only

Tags: gdb, solaris, readonly

I'm debugging a program (in Solaris) that may be writing into memory marked read-only, but I'm unsure how to determine whether that page of memory is actually marked as read-only.

Can I make that determination with gdb?  If not, what can I use?

Comment: Ended up being the segfault is being caused by a data alignment issue.  I haven't finished tracking down the root cause of that, but it boiled down to an assembly instruction:  `st %g1, [ %g2 ]` .... where the `g2` register contains the address `0x602bf53e` -- but it's trying to store a 32-bit quantity at that address but it doesn't fall on a 32-bit boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Solaris you can look at the address space of a process by using the [pmap](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/pmap-1/index.html) command, e.g. `pmap <pid>`. This will display the r/w/x permissions for each mapping; along with other information.

Example from Solaris man page:

```
$ pmap 102905
102905:    sh
00010000    192K r-x--  /usr/bin/ksh
00040000      8K rwx--  /usr/bin/ksh
00042000     40K rwx--    [ heap ]
FF180000    664K r-x--  /usr/lib/libc.so.1
FF236000     24K rwx--  /usr/lib/libc.so.1
FF23C000      8K rwx--  /usr/lib/libc.so.1
FF250000      8K rwx--    [ anon ]
...
 total     1880K
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`pmap`](http://www.opensolarisforum.org/man/man1/pmap.html) and [`pmem`](http://www.solarisinternals.com/si/tools/memtool/index.php) tools.